# How to convert datetime coulmn to date for existing table with records in mysql?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

We had created a employee table with the below structure.

```
Create table employees(
    id int(11) primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    email varchar(50) not null,
    dob datetime not null
);
```

And i have records in this table, with dob data as shown image.

[image]

Now i want to change the dob structure to date from datetime and i tried with below query.

```
ALTER TABLE `employees` CHANGE `dob` `dob` DATE;
```

Once i run this query am getting query error, so please someone guide me.

**Note: Table cannot be truncated.**

Comment: You have foreign key references which would be broken from truncating `datetime` to `date`.

Comment: can't you see the note, i don't want the table to truncate

Comment: You _can't_ convert `datetime` to `date` without truncating, sorry.

Comment: Then how can you say this que is duplicated